# Is there an astronomical name given to the Ewoks' home?

Tags: star-wars, names, ewoks

'Endor' is [not](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor) the actual name of the satellite-moon that the Ewoks dwell([ed?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endor_(Star_Wars)#Impact_damage)) upon.
It's actually the second moon orbiting the planet named Endor, and not Endor itself.

In any Star Wars canon, was there any indication that the moon was given its own name- as Ewoks were prescient enough to name the planet they orbit, [*Tana*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor_(planet)) (*Endor*  to us):

[image]

Comment: The title and the question seem to be completely at odds.  The question is about names for the moon on which the Ewoks live, while the title seems to be asking about names for some explicitly different & separate forest moon orbiting Endor.

Comment: @jwodder nope, the moon where the Ewoks live _is_ the 'second forest moon of endor'.  as in, there's a 'first' moon that is also orbiting the planet.

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing or seeing it referred to as the "_second_ forest moon of Endor," just "_the_ forest moon of Endor." Got a citation for that?

Comment: @MichaelItzoe I recall it being the "second moon" as well. Wookiepedia agrees, but the citation is "interesting".  Apparently the first moon was called "sistermoon". 
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor

Comment: @MichaelItzoe There, I renamed it to something more commonly-identifiable.  Good call.

Comment: OT, but I remember as a kid thinking 'forest moon of Endor' was like 'city of New Orleans', so I just called it Endor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to have covered your bases there rather well. I cannot pick a piece of EU or novel where it explicitly states 'the moon of Endor is known as ...'. Though there is the references below.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor

This link lists the name Sanctuary moon as the name of the forest moon of Endor. There is also this passage - "Endor was set aside as a protected nature reserve during the Galactic Republic, giving it the name Sanctuary Moon. "

This makes my understanding at the satellite is known as "the forest moon of Endor" or Sanctuary moon, whilst the planet is named Endor or Tana

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember the Emperor referring to it as the Sanctuary Moon while he and Vader were trying to turn Luke to the Dark Side.

Comment: Where does the Emperor say so? Can you provide a timestamp, a link, a quote?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuPe-ly0BHM  at 2:39

Comment: Good catch. A fully canonical answer. And well-supported, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the first edition of West End Games Star Wars rpg it tells of Endor orbiting nothing as the planet it orbited was destroyed millenia ago.  The second edition also says this.  The encyclopedia of Planets in Star Wars also says it.  None of them give name for the planet as it was lost to history.

Comment: Huh? According to the question, Endor is a planet, not a moon orbiting a planet. (Unless I'm misunderstanding?)

Comment: Are you referring to the forest moon that the shield generator is on when you say "the planet" that doesn't have a name?

Answer (score -4):

It is called petitmaison which directly translate from French to English as "home of little" or I guess home of "Ewoks"